# Need to call js function for inputs created by for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML:

```
<?php foreach($proddata as $p){ ?>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="checkbox" name="productnames[]" id="productnames" value="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" style="width:10%;" <?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  />
               <?php echo $p->p_name;?>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="form-group" id="products">
               <input type="number" id="<?php echo "h".$p->p_id;?>" name="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" class="val" onkeyup="myFunction()"  onclick="myFunction()"  
                      value="<?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) {echo "1";} ?>" min=1 step=1 placeholder="height"/>
               <input type="number" id="<?php echo "w".$p->p_id;?>" name="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" class="val" onkeyup="myFunction()"  onclick="myFunction()" 
                      value="<?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) {echo "1";} ?>" min=1 step=1 placeholder="width"/>
                <input type="number" id="<?php echo "qt".$p->p_id;?>" name="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" class="val" onkeyup="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) {echo "1";} ?>" min=1 step=1 placeholder="quantity"/>
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo "r".$p->p_id;?>" value="" placeholder="Total"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" value=""/>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

JS:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
    {
     len = document.getElementById("length_array").value;
        for(var i =1;i<=len; i++)
        {
            h = parseInt(document.getElementById('h'+i.value);
            w = parseInt(document.getElementById("w1").value);
            q = parseInt(document.getElementById("qt1").value);
            if(!h=="" && !w=="" && !q=="")
            {
             total= h * w * q;
             document.getElementById("r1").value = total;    
            }                
        }          
    }</script>
```

View:

[image]
This allows me to calculate total of only 1st row. I need to allow call myfunction() for each product whenever the height and width values are fed into the input boxes. I am stuck. Thnks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: where is the "length_array" element? This seems to be what determines how many times you loop, but we can't see it in your code, or see what it contains. Also `document.getElementById("r1").value = total;  ` overwrites the same field every time you loop. Surely `document.getElementById("r" + len).value = total;` would be correct? Same for w1 and qt1

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery...?

Comment: @GyandeepSharma: Yes.

Comment: I gave you the solution... Please go through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following.

I added some classes and set up the event handler onload

NOTE: IDs must be unique

Also you can create a grand total and add to it in the inner loop too

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var vals = document.querySelectorAll(".val");
  for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) { // loop over all input with class val
    vals[i].oninput = function() {
      var tots = document.querySelectorAll(".total");
      for (var i = 1; i < tots.length + 1; i++) { // loop over all totals to get index
        var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("h" + i).value),
          w = parseInt(document.getElementById("w" + i).value),
          qt = parseInt(document.getElementById("qt" + i).value);
        h = isNaN(h) ? 0 : h;
        w = isNaN(w) ? 0 : w;
        qt = isNaN(qt) ? 0 : qt;
        var total = h * w * qt;
        document.getElementById("r" + i).value = total>0?total:"";
      }
    }
  }
  vals[0].oninput(); // perform initial calculation
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="productnames[]" id="productnames1" value="x" style="width:10%;" /> Name 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form-group" id="products">
      <input type="number" id="h1" name="h1" class="val" value="1" min=1 step=1 placeholder="height" />
      <input type="number" id="w1" name="w1" class="val" value="1" min=1 step=1 placeholder="width" />
      <input type="number" id="qt1" name="qt1" class="val" value="3" min=1 step=1 placeholder="quantity" />
      <input type="text" class="total" id="r1" value="" placeholder="Total" />
      <input type="hidden" id="x1" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="productnames[]" id="productnames2" value="x" style="width:10%;" /> Name 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form-group" id="products">
      <input type="number" id="h2" name="h2" class="val" value="1" min=1 step=1 placeholder="height" />
      <input type="number" id="w2" name="w2" class="val" value="1" min=1 step=1 placeholder="width" />
      <input type="number" id="qt2" name="qt2" class="val" value="0" min=0 step=1 placeholder="quantity" />
      <input type="text" class="total" id="r2" value="" placeholder="Total" />
      <input type="hidden" id="x2" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is just one issue, whenever i enter a value in any of the "val" class inputs, the Total input box shows 0,instead of placeholder -"total" for all the rows. i need the placeholders. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I changed to `document.getElementById("r" + i).value = total>0?total:"";`

Comment: I also triggered the calculation now onload using `vals[0].oninput()`

Comment: Yup. Works. 
// loop over all input with class val: Can u help with that too? Sorry for the trouble but i am a little out of my depth here.

Comment: What is the question? the code does not need to be changed - if all 3 inputs have class="val" they will have the oninput event handler assigned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162511/discussion-between-rashmy-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 1):

I made some change in your code Its working...

Please check

I change the function calling event to `onChange()` from `onkeyup()` this call function while making change in inputs.

While calling function send current `$p->p_id` to function.By this the selection of row get easier.

```
<?php foreach($proddata as $p){ ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" name="productnames[]" id="productnames" value="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" style="width:10%;" <?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  /><?php echo $p->p_name;?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="form-group" id="products">
            <input type="number" id="h-<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" name="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" class="val" onkeyup="myFunction(<?php echo $p->p_id;?>)" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) {echo "1";} ?>" min=1 step=1 placeholder="height" />
            <input type="number" id="w-<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" name="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" class="val" onkeyup="myFunction(<?php echo $p->p_id;?>)" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) {echo "1";} ?>" min=1 step=1 placeholder="width" />
            <input type="number" id="q-<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" name="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" class="val" onkeyup="myFunction(<?php echo $p->p_id;?>)" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['productnames'])) {echo "1";} ?>" min=1 step=1 placeholder="quantity" />
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo "r".$p->p_id;?>" value="" placeholder="Total"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $p->p_id;?>" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<script>
   function myFunction(id){
        h = parseInt(document.getElementById('h-'+id).value);
        w = parseInt(document.getElementById('w-'+id).value);
        q = parseInt(document.getElementById('q-'+id).value);
        if(!h)h=1;
        if(!w)w=1;
        if(!q)q=1;
        total= h * w * q;
        document.getElementById('r-'+id).value = total;   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, i needed to show total for onclick event of each row.

Comment: change `onChange()` To `onkeyup()`